# UIView position relative to another UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm trying to create a custom accordion-list. On tap it should expand the tapped line and the next lines should change their position relative to the expanded one. By tapping it again it should contract. By tapping another non-expanded line, the expanded line should contract and the tapped one should expand.

I tried to solve this by using subviews with TapGestureRecognizers. I have a undefined number of lines. On tap I change the height of the tapped line and rearrange the position of the following lines manually. Now, it's getting really confusing to handle all possibilities of expanding/contraction/positioning. I'm looking for a more comfortable way to handle this.
Is there any way to align the subviews vertically so that the positions of the lines change automatically if one height changes?

Comment: It's actually easier to implement accordion list with `UITableView`. I am sure Apple hard somewhere an example of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better solution is to use the tableView where the cells will contribute your custom view.Positioning and all will be handled by tableview itself.

Comment: I tried to change the height of one cell but now Cell A overlaps Cell B. Is there a flag I have to set ?

Comment: call within animation block or reload the whole table

Comment: ok great, that worked. On table:DidSelectRowAtIndexPath: I save the selected cell's indexPath in an array and reload the table. Now, in tableView:HeightForRowAtIndexOPath: I use the array of indexPaths to determine wich cell I have to resize.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with iOS 6, this should be pretty easy with constraints.  Specify that each view is to be located a certain distance from the bottom of the one above it, and when the ones above it move or expand or contract, that constraint should force everything else to move to keep the gap you specified.

EDIT: I just realized that you mentioned in your OP that you may not know for sure how many views you are going to need ahead of time.  That probably makes the table view method others have suggested more favorable.  It is still possible to do with constraints though (and I found a pretty [detailed tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) that goes over everything).

Comment: What would the constraint look like for me? I've never used constraints before. Something like this ? V:[line(==10)] ? And what NSLayoutFormatOptions should I use?

Comment: Ok, then I'll try using the tableview

Comment: @matthisb: there is a very thorough tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) that you could refer to if you decide to go this way with it.